# How to solve 'Windows could not start the MongoDB Server (MongoDB) on Local Computer, service-specific error code 48'?

Tags: mongodb, windows, service

Windows could not start the MongoDB Server on Local Computer (service-specific error code 48)

I tried the existing solutions in the internet.
Basically did all the reachable things.

MongoDB service is not starting in the Services. When I press Start in the Services, it pops this error message.

[image]

Comment: Have a look at mongod log file.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. The issue was the binded IP which in the config file, I put a wrong IP for that. So, then I recheck all the things and then this caught.

After the change always be mindful to restart the service.